# wiping old phone

Tags: iphone

I just got a new iphone today.   I set it up and restored the old information onto my new phone.   I went back into my old phone to erase everything on it and it keeps telling me the icloud password is invalid.  I know it isn't because I used the same password to get into my new phone.  How do I erase the old phone?

Comment: Have you tried logging into iCloud on the web and resetting your password there?  You'll have to use the new password on the new iPhone, of course, but it might be just what the old iPhone needs to allow you to log-in and erase it.

Comment: I wouldn’t change a password unless you can’t follow the steps - ideally you never have to share your password or your pass code to the device. Only change them if they are compromised

Answer (score 1):

Apple made it so there is no way to erase and reuse iPhone without knowing the iCloud password.

You can perform the actual Restore by putting it in DFU mode and using Finder/iTunes, but you'll need the original iCloud credentials to reactivate it.

Comment: This isn’t true. I suppose you could say, without the passcode and AppleID account, you can’t command an erase from iOS directly by tapping on the screen.

Comment: @bmike fixed. In practice, this is still true: you need to activate the phone with Apple in order to use it, and you need the iCloud password for that, if Find My is enabled on iPhone.

Comment: They’re not asking how to reactivate it, but you are 100% correct. Nice edit and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apple has all the steps needed here - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351

Unless you need to get health data off an Apple Watch, it doesn’t [matter much in the end](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/435499/5472) if you don’t unravel all the data before you wipe and give away the old device. I prefer to do the steps while I have possession of the old phone so I know they’re done when I can, though.