# Erase content on sold phone

Tags: iphone, ios, secure-erase

I sold my phone to a friend. He need to erase content so he can use phone.  I don't know if I gave him the correct password.  If I change my apple password on my new phone will he be able to use it on my old phone to erase content as well?

Comment: Change your password right away. Tell this person not to use your password. He may inadvertently delete things from your account. Giving that person your password was a really bad idea. Never do that again.

Answer (score 11):

Don’t give them your password. It’s not needed to erase the device as long as you still know your AppleID and password - the [link at the bottom erases iPhones in recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306) and they can do that without your secrets if they have physical custody of the device.

For you, this guide is your checklist - jump to the part where “you no longer have the device”.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351

The erase device (step one above) is a little easier on them if you trust them to know your old passcode but they can connect it to a computer and [restore/erase it without knowing your passcode or your AppleID password.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/410601/5472)

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

If they don’t know your passcode, start here and work back up if needed

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306