# Old ipad reset issue

Tags: ipad

I bought a new iPad. I forgot to turn off “Find my iPad,” on the old one beforehand.  I had already backed all up on iCloud. After I loaded my new device, I reset and cleared all content on my old one.  A prompt came up asking me to sign in my Apple ID. Not sure if it automatically disabled Find My iPad. But I want to sell the old one and I have no idea if Find my iPad was disabled..So now I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Do you still have access to your old iPad? Does it show up in Find My?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a nice checklist that covers this in detail.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351

Depending on what you set up and who has possession, the steps needed vary. One thing, [you don’t need to give anyone your passcode or password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/435499/5472) - they can erase the device without any of that. As long as you can get to the web interface for your account, you can release the iPad sooner or later.